# Is this a photo of today's Soyuz anomaly happening in flight seen from the ISS? What are the little dots?

Tags: iss, soyuz-spacecraft, russia, soyuz-launcher, emergency

ISS Exp. 57 Cmdr. and ESA Astronaut [Alexander Gerst](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Gerst)'s [Tweet](https://twitter.com/Astro_Alex/status/1050385043980472322/photo/1) today says:

> Glad our friends are fine. Thanks to the rescue force of >1000 SAR professionals! Today showed again what an amazing vehicle the #Soyuz is, to be able to save the crew from such a failure. Spaceflight is hard. And we must keep trying for the benefit of humankind #Exp57 #SoyuzMS10

and it contains the image below. I've also added a cropped, enlarged and sharpened section for better viewing/discussion.

Does this in fact show the emergency return to Earth that happened today, seen from the ISS? If so, it must be at a fairly long focal length. Can someone explain the details (the two or three dots near the top, and the squiggly smoke)?

I understand that at the time of launch the site will be roughly under the ISS' orbit, but is this just a coincidence that the ISS just happened to pass over, or does that happen frequently as some result of phasing?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Based off of a quick Google Images search, the original source of this image is the tweet that you linked to today. Based on context, it's likely this was today's abort-to-ground launch. It looks to me -- an untrained space enthusiast who hasn't spent time analyzing this image -- like this was shortly after the first stage cutoff and second stage engine start. If I were to investigate further to give an actual answer, I'd compare it with the video that NASA released on YouTube earlier to see if I can match the times.  I suspect, though, that this was before the second stage engine cut off.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is a photo of the MS-10 launch. This image also appears on [Alexander's flickr page](https://www.flickr.com/photos/astro_alex/44335552035/in/photostream/), with timestamp "October 11, 2018" and the title *"Image of the Soyuz MS-10 launch as seen from the International Space Station"*.